# SQL Server: erro 7303 (architecture mismatch)

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Já pesquisei bastante, mas ainda não encontrei uma solução para o meu caso. Preciso criar um linked server para um banco em Access (arquivo mdb). Uso o SQL Server 2012 Express x64 no Windows 8.1 x64. Eu executei o odbcad x32 (que fica dentro da pasta syswow64) e criei o data source apontando para o meu arquivo:

[image]

Porém, quando vou criar o linked server, aparece o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As soluções que encontrei citavam que era pra fazer isso, pois o servidor x64 é capaz de reconhecer drivers x32. Qual é o meu erro?